# Execute task every hours at specific milliseconds Android

Tags: android, time

For my app I need to execute a task every hours but at specific time.
A server return to me a number of millisecond for example : 100ms, so I need to execute a task at :

- 00:00:00.100
- 01:00:00.100
- 02:00:00.100 etc ....

If the number is 3500 for example, I need to execute task at :

- 00:00:03.500
- 01:00:03.500
- 02:00:03.500 etc ...

I know how to run a task every 1 hour with an interval but I don't know how to do it at a specific time. If anyone has a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the exact ms (and I really, REALLY doubt that you do) you're out of luck.  Android isn't a real time OS, because Linux isn't a real time OS, and doesn't make those assurances.  If you just need really close to the time (like exact to the second), AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle will be called even in low power mode.  However there is no repeating version of that, so you'll need to implement that yourself if needed.  And AlarmManager doesn't persist alarms through reboot, so if you need it you'll have to do that.  Finally you have about 10s to execute whatever you need or take appropriate measures like wake locks to do more.

This also requires the schedule exact alarm permission.  Read the docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: My application is always in the foreground on my device, it is only intended to run this application. I am therefore not obliged to go through AlarmManager?
I don't expect millisecond precision but at least 10ms I think it's doable

Comment: No, it isn't.  Linux is not the type of OS that gives those promises.  It could be scheduling something else on all cores in those 10ms.  If something is already running on a core and doesn't yield, Linux typically schedules for 100ms blocks.  There's an entirely different type of OS called an RTOS that does provide those promises.  If you really need that kind of exactness, look into that kind of hardware.

Comment: But if you really are in the foreground at all times and the screen never goes off, you can just start up a thread, have it calculate how many ms to wait, and sleep for that long.  It will come close (within a second).  But if there's any chance you ever may not be foreground or that the screen could go off, use AlarmManager.

Comment: Hi Gabe, Okay thanks for your answer, I will do as you say.
Calculate the time I have to wait until the first iteration and then I run the task every 1 hour